# Free Shipping Limited To A Certain Carrier

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart, free-shipping, usps

Is there a way to make free shipping for only a certain item and for only "USPS Media Mail".

I.E. I want people to be able to add "product a" to shopping cart and when they see the shipping rates, it should be displayed as follows:

- UPS $10.00 USPS
- Media Mail: FREE
- Priority Mail: $10.00